# Prevent language translation of resource file in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, localization, multilingual, multilingual-app-toolkit

When using the Multilingual App Toolkit extension (version 4) in Visual Studio (2015) is there any way to prevent one of the resource files in the project from being translated?

In the Multilingual App Toolkit I have two languages added using `Add translation languages...`

I've now added a new resource file `resourceImages.resx` to my WinForms project to contain images that should not be localized.

The toolkit has automatically created `resourceImages.fr.resx` and `resourceImages.de.resx`.  Is there any way I can prevent this - I do not want the images to have translated versions and I don't want them to appear in the xlf translation files that our translators will receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of the Multilingual App Toolkit has now answered this question in the Q&A tab [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5e2a913c-709c-44e6-8b90-a552eede1903)

> There is no option to ignore resource files with MAT.  However, by default the entry in the XLF file is a reference to a image location and not the image itself.  Marking the image resource(s) as Translate = 'No' in the XLF file will prevent the images references from being added to the target language image resource files. This is because resources with a Translate = 'No' are not added to the target resource file.  This should allow you to use a single image for all languages without any project bloat.